# Weird characters instead of image

Tags: html, image, jsp, postgresql, binary

I have `Servlet` `API/JSP` media portal. Today I added `JQuery` plugin for viewing images, which are dynamically stored and loaded by `PostgreSQL` bytea field. Everything works fine if I try to view images on my local machine. But when I try to view images from DB - I get a lot of weird characters instead of img. On the web page there are all images from DB and I see that they render correctly. So it's not the trouble in the header (set to img/jpg). I just can't view them in a plugin for some reason. This is how I load them. I am looping through all the image's ID and returning binary data from `servlet`, which becomes a src attribute of an image.

```
<c:forEach var="imageID" items="<%= currentUser.getImageIDs()%>">
<a class="group2" href="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/imageservlet?id="%>${imageID}"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/imageservlet?id="%>${imageID}" ></a>
</c:forEach>
```

Please, point me to the solution of this problem. If some more info is needed - no problems.
Thanks in advice.
Nazar

Answer (score 0):

Bytea types can pose some difficulties in PostgreSQL because many interfaces require separate unescaping, and the escape methods available can change with PostgreSQL versions.  There isn't enough information here to give an answer but there is enough to get you started troubleshooting.

In general, you have a few possible cases of problems with bytea types.

1. Are you properly handling escaping on input?
2. Are you accidently mangling the file on input?
3. Is the file properly being unescaped on output?
4. Is the file being mangled on output?

Now problems 2 and 4 are in your code, while 1 and 3 would be generally related to the framework you are using (and possibly misuses there).  However you need to start by running full circle tests and comparing final output to input, and then stepping through to see what has changed (a hex editor can be helpful in identifying certain types of problems).